# How to call a list from a function within a Kivy GUI class to a function within another within Kivy GUI class? Both classes are in the same .py file

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface, kivy

I have some experience with Python before but am a beginner in Kivy GUI and currently trying to make a questionnaire app. In the 1st class I have a list get created in 1 of the functions and would like to use the list in the 2nd class. I've tried to return the list at the end of the function that contains it and call it in the 2nd class by using class_name().function_name and then function_name.list_name but it still doesn't work as I wanted.

My code is as below:

```
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Questionnaire1App(App):

    def build(self):
        #window layout
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 10, size_hint_y = None, padding = (200,50))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height = self.layout.setter("height"))

        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

        #title
        self.ttl = Label(text = "title",
                          height = 50,
                          font_size = 24,
                          color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ttl)

        #question + textinput
        self.teach_ask = Label(text = "question?", size_hint_y = None,
                              height = 30, color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.teach_ask)

        self.teach_in = TextInput(size_hint_y = None, height = 30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.teach_in)

        #question + spinner
        self.area_ask = Label(text = "question?", size_hint_y = None,
                              height = 30, color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.area_ask)

        self.area = Spinner(text = "Select item",
                            values = ("1", "2", "3"),
                            size_hint_y = None,
                            height = 30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.area)

        #question + spinner
        self.ncea_ask = Label(text = "question?", size_hint_y = None,
                              height = 30, color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ncea_ask)

        self.ncea = Spinner(text = "Select item",
                            values = ("1", "2"),
                            size_hint_y = None,
                            height = 30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ncea)

        #question + spinner
        self.usas_ask = Label(text = "question", size_hint_y = None,
                              height = 30, color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.usas_ask)

        self.usas = Spinner(text = "Select item",
                            values = ("1", "2"),
                                      size_hint_y = None,
                                      height = 30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.usas)

        #next button
        self.click = Button(text = "Next", size_hint_y = None, height = 30, on_release = self.next, on_press = self.get_cla) #trying to somehow run the get_cla function before next_function
        self.layout.add_widget(self.click)
        
        #scrolling feature
        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        return self.root

    def next(self, obj):
        Questionnaire1App().stop()
        Window.close()
        Questionnaire2App().run()

    def get_cla(self, obj1):
        cla = ["", "", ""] #list of strings, can be up to 21 items

        return cla

class Questionnaire2App(App):

    def build(self):
        #window layout
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 10, size_hint_y = None, padding = (200,50))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height = self.layout.setter("height"))

        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

        #question + spinner
        self.class_ask = Label(text = "question?", size_hint_y = None,
                              height = 30, color = "black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.class_ask)

        clas = Questionnaire1App().get_cla #trying to somehow call the list cla from get_cla function in Questionnaire1App but wouldn't work
        c = clas.cla #give error below

        self.cla = Spinner(text = "Select item",
                           values = (c[0], c[1], c[2]),
                           size_hint_y = None,
                           height = 30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.cla)

        #scrolling feature
        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        return self.root
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Questionnaire1App().run()
```

The error the program gives when it reaches `c = clas.cla`:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'function' object has no attribute 'cla'
  File "C:\...\try.py", line 169, in build
    c = clas.cla
  File "C:\...\try.py", line 138, in next
    Questionnaire2App().run()
  File "C:\...\try.py", line 183, in <module>
    Questionnaire1App().run()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cla'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:
In the function in class 1

```
self.cla = [your_list]
```

And then when you need it in the second class do:

```
C = Questionnaire1App.cla
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function **without argument** so, you need to initialize the `obj1 = None` in order to call that function without argument
replace the function `get_cla` in class `Questionnaire1App` with the code below:

```
def get_cla(self, obj1 = None):
    cla = ["", "", ""]
    return cla
```

The way you are calling that function like the code below, is not the right way to call a function:

```
clas = Questionnaire1App().get_cla
c = clas.cla
```

**rather you should call it like the code below**:

```
clas = Questionnaire1App()
c = clas.get_cla()
```

The returned value from the function will be assigned to `c`.

You might be confused with the line `self.click = Button(text = "Next", size_hint_y = None, height = 30, on_release = self.next, on_press = self.get_cla)`. The reason is that, `on_press = self.get_cla` is automatically passing a value to the function `get_cla` as an argument.

Try the stated changes, This will help.

**Revision:**

I have added the complete modified code as you expected.

```
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class area:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "This is the text for area class"

class Questionnaire1App(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.area = None
        self.ncea = None
        self.usas = None
        self.cla = []
        # self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, padding=(200, 50))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter("height"))
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.ttl = Label(text="title", height=50, font_size=24, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ttl)

        self.teach_ask = Label(text="question?", size_hint_y=None, height=30, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.teach_ask)
        self.teach_in = TextInput(size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.teach_in)

        self.area_ask = Label(text="question?", size_hint_y=None, height=30, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.area_ask)
        self.area = Spinner(text="Select item", values=("1", "2", "3"), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.area)

        self.ncea_ask = Label(text="question?", size_hint_y=None, height=30, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ncea_ask)
        self.ncea = Spinner(text="Select item", values=("1", "2"), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.ncea)

        self.usas_ask = Label(text="question", size_hint_y=None, height=30, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.usas_ask)
        self.usas = Spinner(text="Select item", values=("1", "2"), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.usas)

        self.click = Button(text="Next", size_hint_y=None, height=30, on_release=self.next, on_press=self.get_cla)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.click)

        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        return self.root

    def next(self, obj):
        self.stop()
        Window.close()
        Questionnaire2App(self.cla).run()

    def get_cla(self, obj1):
        cla = ["", "", ""]
        cla[0] = self.area.text
        cla[1] = self.ncea.text
        cla[2] = self.usas.text
        self.cla = cla
        # return cla


class Questionnaire2App(App):
    def __init__(self, cla = []):
        super().__init__()
        self.cla = cla
        # self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, padding=(200, 50))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter("height"))
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.class_ask = Label(text="question?", size_hint_y=None, height=30, color="black")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.class_ask)

        self.cla_1 = Spinner(text="Select item", values=(self.cla[0], self.cla[1], self.cla[2]), size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.cla_1)

        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Questionnaire1App().run()
```

I've tried it in my environment, It is working.

Comment: In the code above I did simplify it a bit without realising it would make a total difference. I was wanted to get the option chosen from the spinner by `area_code = self.area.text` inside get_cla function. area_code will directly affect what goes into the cla list. And apparently self.area.text will only work if the second argument is there, ie. if obj1 = None then it gives the error of `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Questionnaire1App' object has no attribute 'area'`
However as you stated above, if obj1 is not = None, I cannot call it later. Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: The exception you have stated, is not because of `obj1 = None`. It is throwing Exception because in `Questionnaire1App` there is not attribute `area`.
what is `area` here? is this a class or something else?
please provide complete details, if possible.

Comment: self.area is a spinner I have in function build inside Questionnaire1App class, which should show up a spinner with options to choose from and I want to get the text of the spinner after an option is chosen (ie. to know what option the user chose) because this will affect what goes into the list cla

Comment: See the changes in answer under revision heading. It should work probably.